OnTap is not reacting inside of Positioned widget in Stack
here is my code, I can't trigger ontap event. it's like, something covered up the GestureDetector() widget. I even tried InkWell() widget too, No event is happening. what's the issue here?
        body: Stack(        
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Positioned(
                top: 150.h,
                left: 25,
                right: 25,
                child: Container(
                    // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                    height: 600.h,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 25.h, horizontal: 15.w),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            spreadRadius: 0.3,
                          )
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    child: Column(
                      
                      children: [
                        boldText("Choose one or more option", 22,
                            color: Colors.black87),
                        siVer(35),
                        ListTile(
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          leading: Icon(Icons
                              .dashboard_customize_sharp), // TODO: replace the icons
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/request');
                          },
                          title: normText(
                              "I need spead with a doctor because I feel sick",
                              15,
                              color: Colors.black87),
                      ],
                    )))
          

How can I solve this issue? Is there any package to solve this issue?

It's working perfectly fine. You just need to reformat it.

but how?? ontap is still not working

I have tried your code and it's working perfectly. Okay, I will post output as an answer with proper formatting below.

Here's a solution with formatting:
body: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 150,
            left: 25,
            right: 25,
            child: Container(
              height: 600,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25, horizontal: 15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    spreadRadius: 0.3,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Choose one or more option",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard_customize_sharp),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/request');
                    },
                title: Text("I need spead with a doctor because I feel sick",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 15),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),

Output:

